R maps look bad in RStudio Plots pane but work when exported
I am using the tmap package in R to create a series of choropleth maps. As I am following an online tutorial, I know what the final maps should look like. However, when I try to visualise the maps in the RStudio Plots pane, the proportions, positions, and text sizes look very different to how they should, and the map itself doesn't look good. Yet when I export the same map with tm_save(), the proportions work again and it looks like how it did in the tutorial. This works without even having to specify plot size. This is frustrating because it means that I can't use the RStudio Plots pane to refine my map design, and instead have to constantly export my maps to check how they look.
I have a similar problem with RMarkdown: the maps look untidy when generated in the RMarkdown document, but when I export it as an html file, the maps look good again. The proportions also don't work when I use the windows() popup.
I have already tried setting a default size for my Plots pane, have reinstalled tmap, and have searched StackOverflow for more advice, but can't find people with the same problem as me. My RStudio is already on the latest version.

That's because the plots pane is (relatively) small to show the map. You can change it's dimensions but it has limited possibilities. Moreover the map/image itself is resampled down to keep their proportions and fit in the pane. A better view you will have when you click Zoom button and open another view window. But the fact is, the viewer is used just to check the map (at least by myself), the final result (png/html) counts.

Hi Grzegorz, thanks for your reply. I completely understand and know that it's not the end of the world if I have to export my maps all the time. However, I don't understand why everything looks so messy in the plots pane: my peers don't have the same problem and find it much easier and faster to create maps as a result. Do you have any suggestions as to what I could do, or should I just accept that this is an annoying problem that I'll just have to live with?

When you say your peers don't have the same problem, is that when creating exactly the same plots (so it appears to be a setup issue)? Or is the issue with the specific plots you're creating?
